# Why can't I access a jquery select val here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple html select as so:

```
<select id="eventid">
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

The script im using is using this code where I have to grab the select value.

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
<tr class="template-upload fade">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %} 

<td class="post"><label><input type="hidden" name="userid[]" value="$( "#eventid" ).val()" required></label></td>
```

I think it isn't working because of the x-tmpl script header but I have to use that. How can I grab the select value inside this tmpl script?

Thanks

Comment: What is type="text/x-tmpl"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a quote mismatch, change :

```
value="$( "#eventid" ).val()"
```

to

```
value="$('#eventid').val()"
```

and hopefully whatever strange templating system you're using lets you use jQuery directly in value attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript isn't executed in `value` attributes. It's only executed in `onXXX` attributes, and in `href` when the URI scheme begins with `javascript:`.

You should use an `onsubmit` handler for the form that copies the select value into the form field.

Comment: what do you mean by "copies the select value into the form field."?

Comment: Something like `$("input").val($("#eventid").val())`

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand. I'm fairly new to js.

I have this right now:

<form id="fileupload" class="form-inline" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="sendData()">

<select id="eventid">
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
</select>

function sendData() {
   $("input").val($("#eventid").val());
   
  }

Comment: You need to specify what event should trigger copying the select value into the input. Should it be when the user submits the form, when they click on something, or what? Then you have to write a handler for that event, and it should do something like what I wrote. You seem to have an array of inputs -- should the select value be copied into all of them? It's really not clear what you're trying to do, so all I can do is give general hints. Now it's time for you to use your programming skills to implement what you actually want.